# Equate Table in Mathematica

Tags: arrays, wolfram-mathematica, element

I have two arrays they are,

```
 aa={a,b} 
 bb={1,4}
```

I can only play with arrays `aa` and `bb`.
How can I make `a=1` and `b=4`?
That means if I enter `a` (then press <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd>), the output is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `MapThread` like so:

```
aa={a,b}
bb={1,4}
MapThread[Set, {aa,bb}]
```

This will do the same as going through and setting them one and one, like `a = 1` and `b = 4` .